# Modifying Footline and First Page

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I want to modify the footline in the Luebeck theme by displaying my institution instead of the title. Also I want to display the name of the university where I am presenting instead of my parent institution in the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Luebeck}

\title[my institution]{title}
\author{names}
\institute{university where I am presenting}
\date{date}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]